# QEMU/KVM Libvirt forwarding

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, linux-kvm

I am using OpenSUSE Leap 42.2 on a Dell Inspiron 1545. There was an error on default virtual network on KVM:

> Error starting network 'default': internal error: Check the host setup: enabling IPv6 forwarding with RA routes without accept_ra set to 2 is likely to cause routes loss. Interfaces to look at: eth0, wlan0

Google found no results to that error.

- Am I the only one who has that problem?
- How do I set `accept_ra` to 2?
- Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` or place your own any.conf file to `/etc/sysctl.d/` folder with lines:

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 2
net.ipv6.conf.wlan0.accept_ra = 2
```

After reboot this error will gone.

Comment: It didn't work after a reboot. I had to run this as root (optionnally replace eth0 with your interface name): `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=2`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the wlan name is 'wlp0s20f3'. It worked for me with the below command -

`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.wlp0s20f3.accept_ra=2` and was able to start the default network as `sudo virsh net-start default`